# Interior derivative of meromorphic 3-form w.r.t complex null vector on twistor space

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, vector-bundles

In [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/2105.06826) paper one finds the following derivation involving twistor space. On page 4, the following $(3,0)$-form $\Omega$ on twistor space
\begin{align}
    \label{add:1.1}
    \Omega=\mathrm{D}^3 Z\otimes \Phi,
\end{align}
is defined, where
\begin{align}
    \label{add:1.2}
    \mathrm{D}^3 Z=\frac{\langle\mathrm{d}\pi \pi\rangle\wedge\mathrm{d}^2 x^{A'B'}\pi_{A'}\pi_{B'}}{2},
\end{align}
is the canonical holomorphic 3-form on $\mathbb{CP}^3$ in the spinor notation and  $\Phi$ which encodes the analytic properties of $\Omega$ is a meromorphic section of $\mathcal{O}(-4)\rightarrow\mathbb{PT}$.  $\Phi$ is restricted to only depend on the fibre direction of twistor space $\mathbb{PT}\rightarrow\mathbb{CP}^1$, i.e. $\Phi$ depends only on the coordinates $\pi^{A'}$.

On page 5, the complex null vectors are introduced, i.e.,
\begin{align}
    \label{equ:1.8}
    \chi=\hat{\kappa}^{A} \hat{\mu}^{A^{\prime}} \partial_{A A^{\prime}}=\partial_{z}, \qquad \bar{\chi}=\kappa^{A} \mu^{A^{\prime}} \partial_{A A^{\prime}}=\partial_{\bar{z}},
\end{align}
where the double-null complex coordinates on the 4D Euclidean space $\mathbb{E}^4$ are
\begin{align}
    \label{equ:1.9}
    z=x^{A A^{\prime}} \kappa_{A} \mu_{A^{\prime}}, \quad w=-x^{A A^{\prime}} \hat{\kappa}_{A} \mu_{A^{\prime}}, \quad \bar{w}=x^{A A^{\prime}} \kappa_{A} \hat{\mu}_{A^{\prime}}, \quad \bar{z}=x^{A A^{\prime}} \hat{\kappa}_{A} \hat{\mu}_{A^{\prime}},
\end{align}
and $\|\kappa\|^{2}=\|\mu\|^{2}=1$.

My question is regarding the following identity on page 6,

\begin{align}
    \iota_{\bar\chi}\Omega=&\langle\mathrm{d}\pi \pi\rangle\wedge(\mathrm{d}\bar{w}\langle\mu\pi\rangle-\mathrm{d}z\langle\hat{\mu}\pi\rangle)\langle\mu\pi\rangle\Phi.\notag\\
 \end{align}

How does one show this? I tried working backwards from the final expression, by substituting $d\bar{w}=dx^{A A^{\prime}} \kappa_{A} \hat{\mu}_{A^{\prime}}$, $dz=dx^{A A^{\prime}} \kappa_{A} \mu_{A^{\prime}}$, and using the identity $\epsilon_{A'C}\epsilon^{DE}=\delta_{A'}^D\delta_{C}^E-\delta_{A'}^E\delta_{C}^D$, giving
\begin{equation}
\langle d\pi \pi\rangle \wedge (dx^{AA'}\kappa_{A}\pi_{A'}\mu^D\hat{\mu}_D).
\end{equation}
However, I am unable to obtain this form of $\iota_{\bar\chi}\Omega$ by starting with the definitions given above for $\bar{\chi}$ and $\Omega$.